# how to check a number of currently logged users redmine

Tags: redmine

I would like to find it a number of users currently logged into Redmine.

There is a last connection information but i would like to find it there is someone logged to redmine before I can reset my server for example.

Many Thanks.
Raf

Comment: Does anyone have got any idea? )